# Shiny Server renderTable rownames issue

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a project I'm working on that we push onto our server and for some reason the renderTable is putting rownames (and thus my align is short a column) on the server version but not the local version. Below is a sample Shiny app and the corresponding outputs (local is the first picture, server is the second). I've tried explicitly setting rownames = FALSE and setting the xtable option to false as well.

Any help is appreciated.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test"),
  fluidPage(
    tableOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table <- renderTable({
    data.frame("Letter" = c("a", "b", "c"),
               "Number" = c(1:3))
  }, align = "cr")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Local]
[image: Server]

Comment: They might be running different versions but I don't think that'd be the problem.

Comment: check your version of `shiny`, your code works fine on mine `1.0.3`

Comment: @PorkChop how did you run it?

Comment: I simply copied and paste your code into Rstudio and all worked

Comment: @PorkChop like my question states, it runs fine locally.

Comment: I tested it on my shiny server too, and everything works fine